# Windows on screen keyboard not popping up when tapping on 1 input field to another

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome, user-input, microsoft-edge

I am facing this issue specifically when the user makes following set of actions:

> If a user taps on an Input field the keyboard pops up (expected and
>   fine behavior). However, if a user taps directly to another input
>   field, without tapping anywhere else keyboard gets hidden (unexpected
>   and buggy behavior). For me to be able to make keyboard pop again, I
>   have to tap outside on any non-input field and tap on input field
>   again.

Not sure if it is related but from looking at other issues, this issue is being faced on Google Chrome (Surface 7). It works fine for Edge browser but I want something that works for Chrome.